# apache 2.2, permission denied on alias. apache user can read..?

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server

I have a freshly setup apache 2.2 on Centos 6.5 and installed centreon (centreon.com)

The Alias is automatically set by centreon installation (and is indeed identical with another running installation.)

Anyhow, accessing `server/centreon` gives a `403 permission denie`d and the `error_log` tells me the same.

Logging in as apache user I can also navigate to the directory and read all the files.
Anyhow, with browser it does not work.

What can be wrong here?
iptables disabled, selinux disabled.

Comment: what is the exact message in error_log?

Answer (score 1):

My first port of call would be the permissions on the files. From the sounds of it the apache user has permission to view the files, but you don't. A simple solution would be to make the owner:group of the files as apache and give the user & group permission to do what they wish (or whatever permissions you feel is required for this application to function).

```
sudo chown apache:apache -R /path/to/parent/folder
sudo chmod 770 -R /path/to/parent/folder
```

At this point you can add your own user to the apache group:

```
sudo useradd -G apache youruser
```

From here both apache and your user will have full rights on the files. This will satisfy any requirement by the application to have the default apache user with full permissions and provide you the same privileges.